Docker compose exposes files as directories in container
I have the following docker compose file nats.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  nats:
    container_name: nats
    image: nats:2.10.18-alpine
    ports:
      - "4222:4222"   # NATS client port
      - "8222:8222"   # NATS monitoring port
      - "6222:6222"   # NATS clustering port
    networks:
      - containers
    volumes:
      - /data/nats:/data
      - /data/nats/config:/config
    command: [
      '-js', 
       '-c', 
       '/config/nats.conf'
    ]
networks:
  containers:
    driver: bridge
    name: services

whenever I run using
docker compose -f nats.yml up 

i get the following output
sudo docker compose -f nats.yml up 
WARN[0000] /projects/containers/nats.yml: the attribute `version` is obsolete, it will be ignored, please remove it to avoid potential confusion 
WARN[0000] Found orphan containers ([redis mysql]) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up. 
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container nats  Created                                                 0.0s 
Attaching to nats
nats  | nats-server: read /config/nats.conf: is a directory
nats exited with code 1

if I disable the -c and following option, I was able to run but inside container, the data folder appears empty, while the nats.conf appears as a directory inside container.
this is how the directory is outside on host
ls /data/nats/config -al
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 simple simple 4096 Aug 27 01:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 simple simple  4096 Aug 27 01:11 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 simple  simple   251 Jul 20 12:58 nats.conf
-rw-rw-r-- 1 simple  simple     0 Aug 27 00:47 notes.txt

but inside container it appears as this
/ # ls /config -al
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root            80 Aug 26 20:04 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Aug 26 20:26 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            40 Aug 26 16:50 nats-server.conf
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            40 Aug 26 20:04 nats.conf

as you can see the files appear as directories. What should I do so that the files appear as files inside container?

Have you tried a docker compose down?  If the volume existed prior to the files that could happen on some hosts (based on your OS).
